# Upload csv to biquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to upload a csv file to big-query and I got this error, do you have an idea about it ?

> ```
>  {'error': '400 Error while reading data, error message: CSV table 
>  encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 0; errors: 100. Please
>  look into the errors[] collection for more details.'}
> ```

Comment: Can you share a sample of your CSV file? Are you sure about the separator, header, and config provided when you load the file? Share your file upload config too.

Comment: It's ok , i got the solution , and that by adding  the parameter max_bad_records to                                       
 LoadJobConfig = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
            schema=schema_results_table,
            skip_leading_rows=1,
            source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
            field_delimiter=delimiter,
            encoding=encoding,
            allow_quoted_newlines=True,
            quote_character=quote_char,
            ignore_unknown_values=True,
            max_bad_records=100000
        )